# Why is this recursive selection sort not working

Tags: c++

I tried to run the code but it just gets stuck. NO error no warning nothing.Is there a better way to write a recursive selection sort?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void scan(int *arr, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
}

void print(int *arr, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void swap(int *p1, int *p2){
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

void insertion(int *arr, int size){
    if(size <= 1)return;
    int i, max = size - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(arr[i]  > arr[max])max = i;
    }
    swap(&arr[max], &arr[i]);
    insertion(arr, size - 1);
}

int main(){
    int *arr;
    int size;
    cout << "Enter the size of the array - ";
    cin >> size;
    arr = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array - ";
    scan(arr, size);
    print(arr, size);
    insertion(arr, size);
    print(arr, size);
}
```

I feel like there is something wrong with the base case of the recursion. How do you generally solve these types of problems.

Comment: there are two different `i` variables and one of them is used, but not initialized.

Comment: Output the parameters on every function call. Alternatively, step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: this is a problem that can be solved by enabling warnings and fixing them: https://godbolt.org/z/6x45xG648

Comment: How long is your Array? If you are using recursion, you have to keep recursion depth in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was 1 small problem in your code. When you call the swap function in the insertion function you have to call it with &arr[max] and **&arr[size-1]**, you can also use **i-1**, as the value of **i** is **size** here.

Code Attached for insertion function

```
void insertion(int *arr, int size){
    if(size <= 1)return;
    int i, maxIndex = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(arr[i] > arr[maxIndex]) maxIndex = i;
    }

    swap(&arr[maxIndex], &arr[size-1]);
    insertion(arr, size - 1);
}
```

The way to debug are many, you can learn to use the gnu debugger which is gdb or use print statements to find out where your code is going wrong.

Comment: Oh I understand now thanks a lot man. You are amazing.